# Как извлечь подстроку, ограниченную двумя символами?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

На вход поступает строка вида

> `asdfsa: asdfdsf=asdfjk34l534jkjf45345; sdfsdf; sdfsdfdsf`

Как извлечь то, что находится между символами "**=**" и "**;**"?

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
string x = Regex.Match(z, @"\=([^=;]*)\;").Groups[0].Value;
```

Работает, но включает ограничители.

Comment: попробуй так: `"\=(.*)\;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте значение из `Groups[1].Value`.
`Groups[0]` это всё выражение целиком.